# How do I query with a join getting all the data in Om Next?

Tags: clojurescript, om, om-next

In Om Next, when having data such as:

```
{:table      {:name "Disk Performance Table"
              :data [:statistics :performance]}
 :chart      {:name "Combined Graph"
              :data [:statistics :performance]}
 :statistics {:performance {:cpu-usage        [45 15 32 11 66 44]
                            :disk-activity    [11 34 66 12 99 100]
                            :network-activity [55 87 20 1 22 82]}}}
```

you can query it with:

```
[{:chart [{:data [:cpu-usage]}]}]
```

to get the chart, join the `data` and dig down `cpu-usage` from the `performance` record:

```
{:chart {:data {:cpu-usage [45 15 32 11 66 44]}}}
```

How do I get the whole performance record instead?

Another potential query is this:

```
[{:chart [:data]}]
```

but it doesn't resolve the join:

```
{:chart {:data [:statistics :performance]}}
```

There are no components as this is only about the data and the query. This is from the exercise number 2 and queries here: https://awkay.github.io/om-tutorial/#!/om_tutorial.D_Queries which uses om/db->tree to run the queries.

Comment: can you expand the [tag:om-next] tag wiki?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
[{:chart [{:data [*]}]}]
```

which gives you:

```
{:chart {:data {:cpu-usage        [45 15 32 11 66 44]
                :disk-activity    [11 34 66 12 99 100]
                :network-activity [55 87 20 1 22 82]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual components with queries and idents, I can't be sure.

However, you should be able to query for `[{:chart [:data]}]`. See `om/db->tree`. Assuming that you have structured your components with the right queries and idents, `om/db->tree` converts your flat app state into a tree so that your read functions see the following data when called:

```
{:table      {:name "Disk Performance Table"
              :data {:cpu-usage        [45 15 32 11 66 44]
                     :disk-activity    [11 34 66 12 99 100]
                     :network-activity [55 87 20 1 22 82]}}
 :chart      {:name "Combined Graph"
              :data {:cpu-usage        [45 15 32 11 66 44]
                     :disk-activity    [11 34 66 12 99 100]
                     :network-activity [55 87 20 1 22 82]}}}
```

If that query doesn't work, `[{:chart [{:data [:cpu-usage :disk-activity :network-activity]}]}]` should certainly do the trick.

Comment: There are no components or idents, this is just that data. I linked to the exercise I'm working on. It is using om/db->tree. Just asking for :data doesn't resolve the join, so, it's not what I want; asking for each specific element is still not *getting them all*; only those specific elements.